# Leveraging Apps from Rally Catalog

Tags: rally, code-rally

I'm seeing if I can take advantage of the source in the rally catalog but having just some basic issues. I tried to take the src code provided via the Story Hierarchy app (https://help.rallydev.com/story-hierarchy) -> https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/storyhierarchy.

Copied that code over to my cloud9 env that I have been using to succesfully build other rally apps that .css. .js, compared the .json files.. Compiled Successfully and tried to run the HTML code in Rally with no success. Is there something else I need to do in my environment or add to the code provided to make this work? Figured this would be the best starting point to get started.

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: This should totally work.  Can you be more specific about the error you're getting?